# How to continue reading from stdin after Control-D on OS/X

Tags: macos, stdin, eof

I would like to use EOF to terminate reading bulk user input, but continue to be able to accept user CLI input.

It seems that Linux allows this behaviour, but OS/X simply shuts down the stdin input steam (as seem from the following test program).

Is there any workaround to allow this to work on OS/X?

Sample output from running on MAC OS/X. Once the EOF is detected, no input can be taken. (Lines begin with >>> are output from the program).

```
TDWONG-M-V08D:$ ./eof_stdin
>>> fgets: zzz
>>> ans=zzz

>>> read stdin again, fgets:
zzz
>>> ans=zzz

TDWONG-M-V08D:$ ./eof_stdin
>>> fgets: >>> ans=
>>> feof(stdin) is true -- EOF detected
>>> read stdin again, fgets:
>>> ans=
```

Sample output from running on Linux. Input is accepted even after the EOF is detected. (Lines begin with >>> are output from the program).

```
[tdwong@tdwong-ubuntu tmp]$ ./eof_stdin
>>> fgets: zzz
>>> ans=zzz

>>> read stdin again, fgets:
zzz
>>> ans=zzz

[tdwong@tdwong-ubuntu tmp]$ ./eof_stdin
>>> fgets: >>> ans=
>>> feof(stdin) is true -- EOF detected
>>> read stdin again, fgets:
zzz
>>> ans=zzz
```

Here is the sample test program:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    char ans[80];
    //
    // read from stdin
    printf(">>> fgets: "); fflush(stdin);
    fgets(ans, sizeof(ans), stdin);
        printf(">>> ans=%s\n", ans);
    if (feof(stdin)) {
        printf(">>> feof(stdin) is true -- EOF detected\n");
    }
    //
    // continue read from stdin
    printf(">>> read stdin again, fgets: \n");
    fgets(ans, sizeof(ans), stdin);
        printf(">>> ans=%s\n", ans);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After detecting EOF you can call the stdio function `clearerr(stdin)`, or `clearerr_unlocked(stdin)`, to clear the EOF status on the `stdin` stream - the `man 3 clearerr` for more details.

HTH

Comment: thanks so much.  Your answer resolve my problem.  For the record, I added "clearerr(stdin)" after the EOF is detected and can continue  to read stdin w/o any issue.